# Android Window Flags: Are flags set in an activty persistent throughout the entire app itself?

Tags: android, android-activity, flags

Here's a small code in one of my activities.

```
Window window = this.getWindow();
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

I have already set the manifest to allow permission to use the WAKE_LOCK. Now, the thing I'm not sure about is the flags set in place in one activity.

Are they persistent throughout the entire app if one of many activities "add" a flag to the Window, like a screensaver flag?

My hunch is that if an activity were to set or add a flag, the flag is only active if the flagged activity is active. If it calls an Intent to start another activity (which didn't specify the flag), the set flag will then be canceled until the intented, unflagged activity finishes, which then it may revert back to its original set state in the flagged activity.

Am I wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question which is best settled with an experiment:

I just tested it by writing a little app with two activities, one opening the other by the click of a button. I have set the Screen timeout to 15 seconds.

Activity1 includes the commands to keep the screen on in its `onCreate()` Method, Activity2 does not. Now while Activity1 is visible the screen does not turn off (obviously). 15 seconds after I open Activity2, it does. So you are right, the Flag is only valid as long as the activity is shown.

Interestingly it does not matter whether you call `finish()` on Activity1. Even if Activity1 is not destroyed (`onDestroy()` is not called, only `onPause()`) the flag will be invalid.

If you return to the first Activity `onCreate()` is actually not called again on Activity1 but th Flag is valid again (since the activity is resumed from the Stack with its previous features).

Comment: It really is best settled with an experiment, however I'm typing on a phone. I'm not near my computer. :(

Answer (score 6):

The `Window` is always reset when an activity starts (`onCreate`). You don't add flags to some global application window state.

You need to setup the `Window` for each `Activity` separately.

> If it calls an Intent to start another activity..

.. the calling `Activity` is destroyed and a new `Activity` is created. The new one has a reset window and once you come back to the initial `Activity` it has the window reset again. But you should get `onCreate` called where you can setup the `Window` again.

Comment: Thank you! :D If only I could choose more than 1 answer.

Comment: This is the most appropriated answer!

Comment: Does that mean if you have set a flag once, you can not reset it until Activity is recreated?

Comment: @sud007 you can change flags while the activity is running. It's just that you'll have to set & restore the flags in `onCreate` manually if you want to keep them across activity restarts (see other answer and e.g. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes#activity-recreation)

Comment: @zapl I tried that in same activity to set a flag once at launch and restore while underlying screen changed. But it cannot work probably because my app is a Single `Activity` app with `Composables` and if I recreate, I will loose all the navigation.